# Permutations of an array of arrays of strings

Tags: php, arrays, permutation

I simply cannot wrap my head around how to solve this problem and after a thorough search on Google with no results, I turn to you with hopes of a solution.

Given the sample array below:

```
array(
    'Type' => array(
        'Toppe',
        'Bukser_og_Jeans'
    ),
    'Size' => array(
        'Extra_small',
        'Small'
    ),
    'Colour' => array(
        'Rod'
    )
)
```

(Note: This is merely a sample; the actual real life situation might have less/more groups and/or elements per group)

How would I go about ending up with the following result?

```
Toppe,Extra_small,Rod
Toppe,Small,Rod
Bukser_og_Jeans,Extra_small,Rod
Bukser_og_Jeans,Small,Rod
```

This is a product search and the API only allows ONE 'refinement' value from each of the Type, Size and Colour groups per query but my assignment requires to query and aggregate the results of multiple API queries.

I'm *thinking* that I need some kind of recursive function to do it, but I have been unable to even produce any code that comes close to my expected result.

All I've been able to find on Google is about permuations of letters or even strings, but where people need e.g. "Red,Blue,Green", "Blue,Red,Green", "Green,Red,Blue", etc., which is, clearly, not what I'm looking for.

I hope someone here understands what I want to do and has an idea of how to do it.

EDIT: The solution as posted by @ikegami, converted to PHP:

```
$iter = 0;
while (1) {
    $num = $iter++;
    $pick = array();

    foreach ($refinements as $refineGroup => $groupValues) {
        $r = $num % count($groupValues);
        $num = ($num - $r) / count($groupValues);
        $pick[] = $groupValues[$r];
    }

    if ($num > 0) {
        break;
    }

    print join(', ', $pick)."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If we had three groups of ten items, we could use a counter that goes from 0 to 999, and split the number into digits.

For example,

```
456 
   % 10 = 6  --------------------------  Item 6 (7th item) in the first group
   / 10 = 45
             % 10 = 5  ----------------  Item 5 (6th item) in the second group
             / 10 = 4
                       % 10 = 4  ------  Item 4 (5th item) in the third group
                       / 10 = 0
```

This algorithm converts a number into base 10. If we wanted to convert to octal, we would have used 8 instead of 10. 10 (or 8) is used throughout because each position has the same number of symbols, but this algorithm also works if the number of symbols varies from position to position.

```
2
   % 2 = 0  ------------------------  Item 0 (1st item) in the first group: Toppe
   / 2 = 1
     ^      % 2 = 1  ---------------  Item 1 (2nd item) in the second group: Small
     |      / 2 = 0
     |        ^      % 1 = 0  ------  Item 0 (1st item) in the third group: Rod
     |        |      / 1 = 0
     |        |        ^
     |        |        |
     |        |        +------------  Number of items in third group
     |        +---------------------  Number of items in second group
     +------------------------------  Number of items in first group
```

This gives us:

```
0 = ( 0 * 1 + 0 ) * 2 + 0 = Toppe, Extra_small, Rod
1 = ( 0 * 1 + 0 ) * 2 + 1 = Bukser_og_Jeans, Extra_small, Rod
2 = ( 0 * 1 + 1 ) * 2 + 0 = Toppe, Small, Rod
3 = ( 0 * 1 + 1 ) * 2 + 1 = Bukser_og_Jeans, Small, Rod
```

The following is a Perl implementation:

```
my %refinements = (
   Type => [
      'Toppe',
      'Bukser_og_Jeans',
   ],
   Size => [
      'Extra_small',
      'Small',
   ],
   Colour => [
      'Rod',
   ],
);

my @groups = values(%refinements);
my $iter = 0;
while (1) {
   my $num = $iter++;

   my @pick;
   for my $group (@groups) {
      my $r = $num % @$group;
      $num = ( $num - $r ) / @$group;
      push @pick, $group->[$r];
   }

   last if $num > 0;

   say join(', ', @pick);
}
```

I know it's not PHP—I don't know PHP—but you're just asking how to solve the problem, not necessarily the code to do it, right? It's my hope that you can understand the above Perl code enough to solve your problem and re-implement it in PHP.

(If I was actually writing a Perl solution, I'd use 
[Algorith::Loops](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Algorithm::Loops)'s `NestedLoops`.)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not Perl ninja - and I can't really understand much Perl :/ It's waay too cryptic :|

Comment: @Thomas Bianchini Daugaard, I added an alternate implementation `@$group` represents the number of elements in that group. Everything else should be near identical to PHP.

Comment: Awesome! That one helped; I didn't really know what @$_ meant at first, heh. It works like a charm!

Comment: Named the loop iterator so you don't have to deal with `$_`.

Comment: @Thomas Bianchini Daugaard, you realise you've now been tainted by Perl, mwuahahahahaha! (Can you tell it's the start of a long weekend?)

Comment: @ikegami, I tried to learn Perl once. I gave up - there are too many ways of doing one thing and $_ and what-not in the same area is confusing :p

Comment: Oh this is exactly what I was looking for. Such an elegant solution.

Answer (score 6):

Just for those wanting a PHP translation:

```
function factor_permutations($lists) {

    $permutations = array();
    $iter = 0;

    while (true) {

        $num = $iter++;
        $pick = array();

        foreach ($lists as $l) {
            $r = $num % count($l);
            $num = ($num - $r) / count($l);
            $pick[] = $l[$r];
        }

        if ($num > 0) break;
        $permutations[] = $pick;
    }

    return $permutations;
}

print_r(factor_permutations(array(array('a', 'b'), array('1', '2', '3'), array('foo', 'bar'))));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for ($i = 0; i < sizeof($Type); $i++) {
  for ($j = 0; j < sizeof($Size); $j++) {
     for ($k = 0; k < sizeof($Colour); $k++) {
       echo $Type[i] . $Size[j] . $Colour[k];
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't really need to be in PHP; whatever popular language anyone posts a solution in, I'm sure I can adapt it to PHP. However, the number of groups (Type,Size,Colour) is dynamic and I have no way of telling how many there _can_ be, but I know that the top at the moment is about 10 (yes, I am aware of the memory aspects of this).

Comment: Converting that to PHP would be the least problem; the real issue here is, as I wrote here that the number of groups can be between 1-10, at the moment, but there is no telling how many there WILL be until the code runs.

Comment: @Thomas Bianchini Daugaard, Keep in mind that 20 3-way choices: 3.5 billion combinations.

Comment: @ikegami, I made that clear to my client and he said that usually it won't be a problem, heh. Normally we're talking maybe 2-4 groups of 1-3 items each. Although that is still _a lot_, that is what they want :|

Answer (score 2):

Well I am not clever enough to comprehend ikegami's solution but I was able to convert it to Javascript for my purposes. I don't know how it works but it is brilliant!

```
lists = [["a","b"],["x","y"],["1","2","3"]] 

function factorPermutations(lists) {  

permutations = []
$iter = 0;

while (1) {

    $num = $iter++;
    $pick = []; 

    for (l in lists) {
        $r = $num % (lists[l].length );
        $num = ($num - $r) / lists[l].length;
        $pick.push( lists[l][$r])
    } 
    if ($num > 0) break;

    permutations.push( $pick);
}
    return permutations
} 

console.log(factorPermutations(lists))
```

Yeah, I left some of the $ signs on variables from the PHP version.

Comment: Added explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have only one nesting level, what you want is:

```
$my_ar[group1][0].(rest_of_the_group_perms[0])
$my_ar[group1][0].(rest_of_the_group_perms[1])
...
$my_ar[group1][N].(rest_of_the_group_perms[K])
```

that is, you can see the problem as having to join two lists/arrays. The first being the first subarray of your array and the second being the (recursively already made) rest.

So you need a function like this:

```
perms($my_arr) {
   foreach($elem in $group1) {
      $return_list[] = $elem.$rest;
   }
}
```

where `$group1` is the first subarray of your array and `$group_rest` is what is left. So:

```
perms($my_arr) {
   $group1 = head($my_arr);
   $group_rest = tail($my_arr);

   $rest = perms($group_rest);
   $return_list = array();
   foreach($elem in $group1) {
      $return_list[] = "$elem, $rest";
   }
   return $return_list;
}
```

but `$rest` is also an array so you have to loop over that too:

```
perms($my_arr) {
   $group1 = head($my_arr);
   $group_rest = tail($my_arr);

   $rest = perms($group_rest);
   $return_list = array();
   foreach($elem in $group1) {
      foreach($relem in $rest) {
          $return_list[] = $elem.$relem;
      }
   }
   return $return_list;
}
```

add the ending condition (null `$group_rest`) and you are set:

```
perms($my_arr) {
   $group1 = head($my_arr);
   $group_rest = tail($my_arr);

  if (length($group_rest) == 0) 
       $rest = array();
  else
       $rest = perms($group_rest);
   $return_list = array();
   foreach($elem in $group1) {
      foreach($relem in $rest) {
          $return_list[] = $elem.$relem;
      }
   }
   return $return_list;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the answer from ikegami is a bit cleaner and easier to read :)

Comment: Haha, true, however easy to translate to PHP in the latter form of his reply ;)

Comment: Keeping all the permutations in memory might not be a good idea.